# Display nested JSON format on Laravel blade

Tags: php, json, laravel

JSON format is saved in MySql column like this:

`[{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3,"children":[{"id":4},{"id":5}]}]`

And I did this in Laravel Blade;

```
@php
  $json = $categories->column;
  $array= json_decode($json , true);
@endphp

@foreach ($array as $key => $value)
  <li>{{ $value["id"] }}</li>
@endphp
```

And I get a result like this;

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3

But I can't get children results. What should I do for it? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code, You should have another loop for children if exists.

```
@php
  $json = $categories->column;
  $array= json_decode($json , true);
@endphp

@foreach ($array as $key => $value)
  <li>{{ $value["id"] }}</li>

    //another loop for children if exists
    @if (isset($value["children"]))
        @foreach ($value["children"] as $child_key => $child_value)
          <li class="childs">{{ $child_value["id"] }}</li>
        @endforeach
    @endif

@endforeach
```

Your output will be this.

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> 4
>
> 5

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried the code you wrote, but I got an error like "Undefined index: children". What should i do ?

Comment: @acnci use `isset($value["children"])` to check that data exist.I update my answer, If you got your answer please accept it , thanks